# Update multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How can i update multiple records in a single statement like this with SQL?:

```
UPDATE records
   SET name='abc' where id=3,
   SET name='def' where id=1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply combine an update with a case statement such

```
UPDATE records
   SET name =
     CASE
       WHEN id = 3 THEN 'abc'
       WHEN id = 1 THEN 'def'
       ELSE name
     END
```

Comment: I think that you should have a `where` on that, otherwise it will do an update on all records in the table.

Comment: @Guffa You have a valid point and I agree with the `where` clause. The downside of this is that we need to make sure conditions in `case` and `where` are the same. Sure, my solution updates all rows, but for the rows that don't fall under these conditions, they are updated from `name` to `name`, which obviously does not change anything

Comment: In most cases it doesn't change anything, but imagine that there is a trigger on update that logs all changed rows to another table...

Comment: @Guffa - Very good point on the triggers.  I suppose you should have logic in your trigger that only logs changed values, but is there perhaps a solution where only rows that meet conditions are updated?  I'd like to have my cake an eat it too.

Comment: @DanielMacias: All records affected by the query will be updated, the only way to keep records from being updated is to add a `where` clause (or use a `join` to the same end).

Answer (score 18):

For just a few records, you could use:

```
update records
set name = case id
  when 1 then 'def'
  when 3 then 'abc'
end
where id in (1, 3)
```

A bit more flexible is to create a result that you can join into the update:

```
update r
set name = x.name
from records r
inner join (
  select id = 1, name = 'abc' union all
  select 3, 'def' union all
  select 4, 'qwe' union all
  select 6, 'rty'
) x on x.id = r.id
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @Guffa I am interested in using the second approach. How many records do you mean by just a few records. I have got potentially a few thousand records to be updated repeatedly in intervals.

Answer (score 5):

```
;WITH vals(id, name)
     AS (SELECT 3,'abc'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,'def')
UPDATE r
SET    name = vals.name
FROM   records r
       JOIN vals
         ON vals.id = r.id
```

Answer (score 4):

Standard SQL:2003 syntax (works on SQL Server 2008 onwards):

```
MERGE INTO records 
   USING (
          VALUES (1, 'def'), 
                 (3, 'abc')
         ) AS T (id, name)
      ON records.id = T.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET name = T.name;
```

Note that `NAME` and `RECORDS` are SQL reserved words.