# Writing dates with RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have a time in R which I would like to write to a MySQL table in a DATETIME column. How can I do that? If I format it as a string SQL doesn't recognize it; if I use `as.POSIXlt` SQL still doesn't recognize it.

I'm just using standard `dbConnect` and `dbWriteTable` statements, which work with non-dates just fine.

Comment: Time variables are imported/exported as character data, so you need to convert these to your favorite date/time representation.

Comment: @agstudy: It's easy enough to convert character data to dates in R. But how do I update a SQL `DATETIME` field from R? Is there a binary format I can use to transfer between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>   As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

So one solution is to format your date in the right format:

```
now <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
now.str <- format(now,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now.str 
[1] "2013-02-26 04:12:24"
```

or in this format

```
format(now,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
[1] "20130226041224"
```

Then update your table using `dbSendQuery`.  Here is an example for creating a dynamic query for any table and any date. Adapt it to your needs.

```
table.Name <- "MY_TABLE"
query <-  paste(paste('UPDATE ', table.Name,sep=''),
                paste('SET datetime_column =' ,"'",now.str,"'",sep=''),
                'WHERE id=1',sep='\n')

cat(query)
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET datetime_column ='2013-02-26 04:12:24'
WHERE id=1

dbSendQuery(con, query)
```

I think also that this should work with `dbWritetable`, once you format your dates in the right format. But I don't have MySQL installed to test it. Try it and let me know if this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work with dbWriteTable, but it might work with dbSendQuery. But I'd have to break up my statements into one write per row if I did that, right?

Comment: @Charles yes if you have one date by row you need to call this for each row. Of course the numbers of updated rows depends on your Where clause. I would try to loop , and if it is slow, I would modify my sql request , to update multiple records. (You can ask new question if you can't do it, but it becomes clearly a sql question, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778140/update-multiple-records-in-sql) may help

Answer (score 1):

I've been using agstudy's solution and then calling this SQL after the dbWriteTable using dbSendQuery. Seems to be working well.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY DateFieldName datetime;
```