# update multiple rows As like Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, sql-update

I am using the following scenario for bulk insertion.

```
Dim queryBuilder As New StringBuilder
queryBuilder.Append("Insert into myTable(col1,col2)values")
Dim loopFlag As Boolean = False
For i As Integer = 0 To 150
  queryBuilder.Append("(" & i & ",'" & i & "th Value'),")
Next
If loopFlag Then
  ' call method to execute the query'
   ExecuteQuery(RemoveTrailingComma(queryBuilder.ToString()))
End If
```

Throughout my project we frequently used these technique for bulk insertion. is there any similar way for bulk update? I had referred these links but they not match with my scenario

- [linl1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778140/update-multiple-records-in-sql)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664684/how-to-bulk-update-mysql-data-with-one-query)

Comment: elaborate what you want to update in bulk...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in the reference link itself. go through that again care fully, or try this:

```
  queryBuilder.Append("ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2)")
```

hence your whole code will be like the following:

```
    Dim queryBuilder As New StringBuilder
    queryBuilder.Append("Insert into myTable(col1,col2)values")
    Dim loopFlag As Boolean = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To 150
        queryBuilder.Append("(" & i & ",'" & i & "th Value'),")
    Next
    Dim mySql As String = RemoveTrailingComma(queryBuilder.ToString()) & "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2)"
    If loopFlag Then
        ExecuteQuery(mySql)
    End If
```